# How to construct xml from another xml using xslt3.0 where xml attribute values should be the new element names

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking for an xslt transformation[version 3.0] from one xml to another xml where attribute values in first xml should be the element tags in transformed xml, for example

**First XML:**

```
<number key="id">2</number>
<string key="name">An ice sculpture</string>
<number key="price">12.50</number>
```

**Transformed XML should be like**

```
<id>2</id>
<name>An ice sculpture</name>
<price>12.50</price>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Use https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#defining-template-rules and https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#xsl-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a template rule like

```
<xsl:template match="*[@key]">
  <xsl:element name="{@key}">{.}</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course the details depend on what else might occur in the file, whether you want to do error handling, etc.